# Can we import any file to our application from icloud?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I know users can upload documents to icloud from their applications. I want to access these documents from my application. Is it possible to access any documents in icloud from our application?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH12-SW1): "To locate documents in iCloud storage, your app must search using an `NSMetadataQuery` object". But I suspect you can't simply access the documents of other apps freely.